# splitting a string(Using reg. exp.) appropriately to extract out some info in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this

```
s = "CITY_NAME == 'Pune' & GENRE in ['$SPORTS$','$CLASSICAL$']$#$CITY_NAME == 'Pune' & GENRE == 'ROMANCE' & QUANTITY >= 25$#$CITY_NAME == 'Pune' & GENRE in ['$ACTION$','$DRAMA$'] & LANGUAGE == 'Hindi'$#$CITY_NAME == 'Pune' & GENRE in ['$MUSICAL$','$Music$'] & EVENT_NAME == 'Dhoom-3'"
```

Actually this string is formed by joining few conditions by '$#$'. So ""CITY_NAME == 'Pune' & GENRE in ['$SPORTS$','$CLASSICAL$']" is condition and so on..

Now my requirement is to filter out the fields(combinedly) present in that string.My o/p should yield

```
fields = ['CITY_NAME ', 'GENRE', 'QUANTITY ', 'LANGUAGE', 'EVENT_NAME ']     ###Only the field name list
```

i have tried doing

```
s1 = s.split('$#$')  
### if i have to go for any one condition, then split by '$#$' gives one list of all condition and i will take 0th index condition
#### then i will split them(the individual condition) at '&'
#### then from that list i  will split at '==' or '>=' or 'in' and take 0th index item then i can find one field name
q = s1[0] ###"CITY_NAME == 'Pune' & GENRE in ['$SPORTS$','$CLASSICAL$']"
qq = q.split('&')  ###["CITY_NAME == 'Pune' ", " GENRE in ['$SPORTS$','$CLASSICAL$']"]
qqq = qq[0]  ###"CITY_NAME == 'Pune' "
qqq.split('==')[0]   ###CITY_NAME
```

I have tried to split considering any one condition. but not able to put all of it in a list comprehenssion statement.

Also i believe there are other simple ways are there like using reg expression.(But i am very week at reg expression.)

Need some code help...Thanks..

Comment: You might need to write a parser that adheres to the grammar, instead of looking for a regex.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/Yxse38, but it might yield wierd results if the same pattern appears in the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
s = ...
fields = set()
for word in s.split():
    if re.match(r'^[A-Z_]*$', word):
        fields.add(word)
fields = list(fields)
print fields
```

This yields: `['CITY_NAME', 'GENRE', 'EVENT_NAME', 'LANGUAGE', 'QUANTITY']`

The reason it separates out your fields is that they are the only words with all-caps that don't have special characters other than `_`.

Comment: Same comment must be here: it might yield wierd results if the same pattern appears in the value.

Comment: It doesn't look at values because the split is on all spaces. The `'` characters don't match the regex. The split gives values like `['CITY_NAME', '==', "'Pune'"]`

Comment: I do agree with Bryce that it does not care about repeated patterns. But @Bryce, suppose a case "CITY == 'INDIA' & GENRE in ['ACTION','DRAMA']"   , in this case it is picking up the 'in' which it should not.(I added small letter case also a-z_ in the pattern)... So is there a way to ignore/exclude few character string like('in','like') from adding to the fields set. Or I should filter those values once i will get fields list.

Comment: Make a set with your exempt words. You can subtract sets from each other.

Comment: @Bryce- exactly !! i am following that. and i was just wondering if i can exclude those keywords or any regex pattern can exclude that... so that i can get the expected o/p in one liner.. Any way after applying your suggestion I can always subtract the sets ...

Answer (score 1):

yes a parser makes sense here .. here is what i have tried to do that(can be include in a function definition later ..)

```
lst = list()  ###empty list to store parsed results

for i in s.split('$#$'):
    #print(i)
    for j in i.split('&'):
        #print(j)
        word = re.split(r'[(==)(>=)(<=)(in)(like)]', j)[0].strip()
        #print(word)
        l.append(word)
print (list(set(lst))) ##o/p:  ['CITY_NAME ', 'GENRE', 'QUANTITY ', 'LANGUAGE', 'EVENT_NAME ']
```

i have tried to avoid some extra char string as those can be used as separator(in, like).

And I feel @Bryce's answer here is more pythonic.

Comment: Mine might be more pythonic, but your answer is more robust.